# Free space 916.6mb on c drive

Tags: system-installation

I installed windows installer wubi, first time you install, it asks how much hard drive you want to install, as you know it has 5gb to 11gb, i chose 5gb to install ubuntu on my computer and was fully installed successfully.

The problem is when i go to my computer>file system>properties it brings pie chart of what capacity is and shows 3.3GB/used 2.4GB which has been used by ubuntu installation/free space of 916.6MB only.

Note:
1)capacity 3.3GB seems to be low
2)ubuntu used 2.4GB for installion
3)free space 916.6MB is very limited memory

Capacity 3.3GB-2.4GB=916.6MB and when i installed 5GB hard drive,how can it be only 3.3GB only.

Comment: Did you enable swap, and how large is it? That may have been accounted under the same limit. (You can see swaps inside Ubuntu using `cat /proc/swaps` from the terminal, or find the file in Windows c:/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk by default.)

Comment: I didn't enable swap,what must i do now.

Answer (score 0):

5Gb would be the unformatted capacity.  By the time it is formatted things like inode tables and other necessary things use roughly 3-5% of the unformatted capacity on that size drive.

The other part of the puzzle is the usual one when people ask "where has my disk space gone?"  Usually, disk drive size is given with the assumed value of 1Mb - 1000000 bytes.  Most operating systems however actually give real byte lengths for files, so the maths means that a 1Mb file is really 1048576 bytes effectively eating another 4%

The wubi installer will let you set much more than 11Gb for the virtual disk size but it seems likely that it was limited to this by the free space on your Windows partition.

A normal default install will be almost 4Gb, so it sounds like you may have a cut down version installed due to the small partition size.